# Typescript type errors don't happen sometimes in my "for..in..." code

Tags: javascript, typeerror

There was no problem when testing, but sometimes the error **"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nickname')"** occurs.
I took some of my code.

```
let seat = [
  null,
  null,
  { nickname: "user1", uuid: "d94e81f3-df66-45f6-a593-c7ee6ccfe261" },
  null,
  { nickname: "user2", uuid: "d94e81f3-df66-45f6-a593-c7ee6ccfe261" },
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
  null,
];
for (const i in seat) {
  if (seat[i].nickname === "user1") {
    seat[i] = null;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(seat);
```

I don't know why sometimes there is no problem and suddenly an error occurs.

```
for (const i in seat) {
  if (seat[i] !== null && seat[i].nickname === "user1") {
    seat[i] = null;
    break;
  }
}
```

I temporarily solved the problem by changing the code in the form above.
I'm curious about the cause...

Comment: Because `null` has no attribute `nickname` .

Comment: I don’t see any TypeScript here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because some of the elements in the array are null values, So you should add a condition to check that as you did `seat[i] !== null` but you can use the Optional chaining operator `?.` as well.

**FYR** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

```
for (const i in seat) {
  if (seat[I]?.nickname === "user1") {
    seat[i] = null;
    break;
  }
}
```

**Ex:**
If you have the data something like the one below, you don't need to add the condition or the optional chaining operator.

```
let seat = [
  { nickname: "user1", uuid: "d94e81f3-df66-45f6-a593-c7ee6ccfe261" },
  { nickname: "user4", uuid: "d94e81f3-df66-45f6-a593-c7ee6ccfe263" },
  { nickname: "user5", uuid: "d94e81f3-df66-45f6-a593-c7ee6ccfe264" },
  { nickname: "user3", uuid: "d94e81f3-df66-45f6-a593-c7ee6ccfe265" },
  { nickname: "user1", uuid: "d94e81f3-df66-45f6-a593-c7ee6ccfe267" },
  { nickname: "user2", uuid: "d94e81f3-df66-45f6-a593-c7ee6ccfe269" },
];
for (const i in seat) {
  if (seat[i].nickname === "user1") {
    seat[i] = null;
    break;
  }
}
```